# Why my password_verify does not work on login?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am learning to create a simple signup and login page which using password_hash and password_verify function.

The sign up page is working fine, and the password_hash are able to encrypt my password in the mysql database. As photo below.

[image]

[image]

Only thing that is not working is that I cannot make the login to work, its always return to error message saying that the password is invalid. I am not using the hashed password, i am using the password that I entered during sign-up (which is just 123).

Below is my code:

1. Login Form:

```html
<div class="InnerDiv">
  <form method="post" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
      <input name="email" type="email" value="<?php echo @$_POST['email']; ?>" class="form-control input-fields" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" required="true">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
      <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control input-fields" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" required="true">
    </div>
    <center>
      <button name="submit2" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-login-form">Login</button>
      <p data-toggle="modal" data-target="#forgotpassdialog" class="forgot-para">Forgot Password?
      </p>
    </center>
  </form>
</div>
```

2. Verify login credentials

```html
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['msg'])) {
  $var=$_GET['msg'];
  echo "<script>alert('$var')</script>";
}




  if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $data = mysqli_query($sql_con,"select *from students where stdemail = '$email' AND password='$password'");
    $datarow = mysqli_num_rows($data);
    
    
    
    if ($datarow > 0) {
        if (password_verify($email, $password)) {
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
      $value3 = $row['id'];
      $_SESSION['sid'] = $value3;
      echo "<script>window.location='/students/dashboard.php'</script>";
        }

        
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>alert('Invalid password')</script>";
     
    }
    
  }
 
 ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated, let me know if more details is needed.

***EDITED:*** I have tried to substitute the $email with the hashpassword value in the password_verify, but still return invalid message.

```html
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['msg'])) {
  $var=$_GET['msg'];
  echo "<script>alert('$var')</script>";
}




  if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $data = mysqli_query($sql_con,"select *from students where stdemail = '$email' AND password='$passwordDB'");
    $datarow = mysqli_num_rows($data);
    
    
    
    if ($datarow > 0) {
        if (password_verify($password, $passwordDB)) {
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
      $value3 = $row['id'];
      $_SESSION['sid'] = $value3;
      echo "<script>window.location='/students/dashboard.php'</script>";
        }

        
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>alert('Invalid password')</script>";
     
    }
    
  }
 
 ?>
```

Comment: You're using `password_verify()` on `$email` and `$password`. You should be using `$password` and the hashed password value you retrieved from the database.

Comment: Hi @TangentiallyPerpendicular I have tried to substitute the value, but still returning invalid message, can you check my edited post?

Comment: Your code is *wide* open to SQL injection attacks because you've directly interpolated user input into your query strings. You should really drop most all of what you're doing and replace these queries with properly parameterized queries/prepared statements, for the sake of your (and your users') data.

Comment: @esqew Thanks for the feedback, I am a new learner too, I will focus about it afterward. Meanwhile can you help to point out whats wrong in my code there if you able to help?

Comment: Side note: Latin1 is pretty much deprecated nowadays. Everything's easier if you switch to UTF-8 (which, in MySQL lingo, would be utf8mb4).

Answer (score 3):

You can't just make up some extra variables and slap them in the code. Your new version is no better than the previous one because you're selecting on a password variable that isn't initialised, and you're not retrieving the hashed password for PHP to check.

There's also the issue of possible SQL injection to address.

So, here's a rewritten version of your code, with some key changes:

- Mysqli is set to throw an exception if there's an error.
- I've used the OOP structure of MySQLi because it's less verbose and easier to follow
- I've restructured your query to used a prepared statement, thus avoiding SQL injection problems
- I've reworked your query to retrieve the student ID and hashed password. No other data is required in this code.
- the code correctly verifies the user-supplied password against the hashed version retrieved from the database

```
session_start();

// Set MySQLi to throw an exception if it detects an error
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

try {
    $sql_con = new mysqli('server', 'usernane', 'userpass', 'database');
    if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        
        // set up query to retrieve id and hashed password
        $query = "select id, password from students where stdemail = ?";
        
        // Prepare query & bind parameters, execute
        $stmt = $sql_con->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        
        // Bind variable to accept the result
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $hashedPassword);
        
        // fetch result. There should only be one, so no loop required.
        $data = $stmt->fetch();

        // Check we retrieved some data, and if so, check the password.
        if ($data && password_verify($password, $hashedPassword)) {
            $_SESSION['sid'] = $id;
            echo "<script>window.location='/students/dashboard.php'</script>";
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Invalid credentials')</script>";
        }

    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I have run this code on my server - it works. If you have problems check your server connection, and ensure that the passwords in your database have been correctly  hashed with `password_hash()`.

Note: for this example the exception handler just displays the exception message. Your live code should not do that, but should handle the exception appropriately.